# Divisions using Arraylists

Tags: java, beginner, object-oriented, array, integer

> **Exercise:** Using Arraylists create a program that makes divisions between two very large numbers (numbers greater than 10 digits).

I did it (the code works), but could my code be improved?

```
public class Main {

    static void division(List<Integer> lista, List<Integer> listb) {

        List<Integer> listResult = new ArrayList<>();

        if (lista.size() <= 10 || listb.size() <= 10) {
            System.out.println("The numbers must be bigger than 10");
        } else {double a = 0, j = 0;
            String Stringnumber = "";
            String Stringnumber2 = "";

            for (int number : lista) {
                Stringnumber += String.valueOf(number);
            }

            for (int number : listb) {
                Stringnumber2 += String.valueOf(number);
            }

            double test = Double.parseDouble(Stringnumber2);
            double test2 = Double.parseDouble(Stringnumber);

            double dividend = 0, divisor = 0;

            if (test >= test2) {
                dividend = test;
                divisor = test2;
            } else {
                dividend = test2;
                divisor = test;
            }

            for (int i = 9; i > 0 && j != 1; i--) {
                if (i * divisor <= dividend) {
                    listResult.add(i);

                    a = dividend - (i * divisor);
                    if (a >= divisor) {
                        i = 9;
                    } else {
                        j = 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println("The result is:");
            for (int i = 0; i < listResult.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(listResult.get(i));
            }

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);

        List<Integer> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> listb = new ArrayList<>();

        System.out.println("Give a number");
        for (char digit : x.nextLine().toCharArray()) {
            lista.add(digit - '0');
        }

        System.out.println("Give another number");
        for (char digit : x.nextLine().toCharArray()) {
            listb.add(digit - '0');
        }
        x.nextLine();

        division(lista, listb);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> for (int number : lista) {
>     Stringnumber += String.valueOf(number);
> }
>
> for (int number : listb) {
>     Stringnumber2 += String.valueOf(number);
> }
>
> double test = Double.parseDouble(Stringnumber2);
> double test2 = Double.parseDouble(Stringnumber);
> ```

It is very confusing that the variable names with a `2` suffix first refer to the first input *a* and then you swap the naming so that the `2` suffix refers to the second input *b*.

It would be better if all names referring to input *a* had an `a` suffix and all names referring to input *b* had a `b` suffix.

Answer (score 2):

At first, I thought that you were going to implement division of two integers, each represented as a list of digits.  But then, you simply concatenate all of the elements of each operand to be parsed as a `double`.  If you're going to cheat on the arithmetic using the built-in floating-point support, then what's the point of the exercise?  In fact, it doesn't even care whether you pass in an `ArrayList` of individual digits `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` or an `ArrayList` of one element `{12345}` — either way, it all gets stringified and parsed as `12345.0d`.

Comment: I could not think of another idea but that (the code)..did I really cheat?

Comment: @Michelle I think you are supposed to implement an algorithm like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division#Method).

Answer (score 2):

#### Doesn't work if the answer is more than a single digit

In your division loop, you never decrease `dividend`, so the loop becomes an infinite loop as long as the dividend is more than 10x the value of the divisor.

You probably want to set `dividend = a` or something like that to avoid the infinite loop.

#### More bugs

Even if you fixed the infinite loop, your division would still be broken.  For example, if you divided `100` by `1` (or equivalently `1000000000000` by `10000000000`) your loop would produce an answer like `999999999991` instead of `100` because you didn't take into account the fact that the divisor and the dividend may be of different lengths.

#### Doesn't really meet the requirement

You aren't actually performing the division using `Arraylists`.  You are using `doubles` instead.  That sort of defeats the purpose of the exercise.